# How to use the U-Boot API?

Tags: c, embedded, embedded-linux, bootloader, u-boot

I am working with the customized atmel version of U-Boot (u-boot-at91) on an atmel evalboard at91sam9x5ek. I use U-Boot to start Linux which is working fine. I want to implement a simple C application that reads and changes some data from the ram. I was able to compile and run the `hello_world` example from the `examples/standalone/` folder. My problem is that I can't figure out how to access the api-functions made available by `glue.h` in the `examples/api/` folder. I can include the file but get the following error message on compiling:

```
u-boot-at91/examples/standalone/hello_world.c:34: undefined reference to `ub_env_set'
```

I added `#define CONFIG_API` to my boards header file so the api is build.

Comment: So how do you expect us to debug your modified code (that you did not post for review) when you only provided one line of the error text (and did not provide the context of the complete message)?  You probably have a linker issue.

Answer (score 0):

The function ub_env_set() is implemented in glue.c, here's what it looks like:

```
void ub_env_set(const char *name, char *value)
{
    syscall(API_ENV_SET, NULL, (uint32_t)name, (uint32_t)value);
}
```

One option would be to compile and link glue.c into your executable.

Another option would be to just add a copy of ub_env_set() to your code and make sure you're including api_public.h as follows:

```
#include <api_public.h>
```

then you should be able to compile.